# How to set default PULL remote in TortoiseGit?

Tags: tortoisegit, pull

I have two remotes configured: "origin" and "upstream".

Changing the *push* default is easy, it's both in the settings window ("Push Default"), and in the push dialog ("Always push to the selected remote branch").

However, I want to change the default *pull* remote. Whenever I pull or fetch, TortoiseGit defaults to "upstream". I want the default to be "origin".

I know I can manually edit the local config and change "remote = upstream" to "remote = origin", but I want to know if there is a way in the TortoiseGit UI to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's called "remote tracking branch". You can set it on the Browse References dialog. Right click on the local branch and then select remote tracking branch.

Comment: If you want to pull/push from/to the very same remote, better use "Set as remote tracking branch" on push dialog in the future which automatically sets both settings.

Comment: Wow you realy have to rigthclick your **local** branch. Tried forever selecting a remote branch and was searching for something like "set as upstream" but no luck...

Comment: I don't get why they don't default to `origin`. Thanks for your answer I would also never have found this myself.